# search synonyms and geo location search

Tags: 7

question 1: I am making a site for a client who wants the search to support synonyms and this is not something that is supported in the search api i believe. so that when a user searches for USA, nodes related to america will show up. Is this possible without the author of the content creating synonyms manually? Is there other options, like embedding google custom search that will support this in any language?

question 2: Is there any module that enables search results to show up in a map for drupal? i have been looking and havent come across any yet..

Thanks in advance:)